# Fancybox does not show ajax content render from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have implemented fancybox to render ajax content from server

Here is the fancybox code

```
  <%= link_to "Disallow Download",reason_path(audio),:class => "reasoning fancybox.ajax" %>



$('.reasoning').fancybox()
```

Now Whenever i link the above link the content get render from server but fancybox does not display it on browser

any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got It Just need to specify `dataType` in ajax property

```
$('.reasoning').fancybox({ajax: {
  'dataType': 'html'
})
```

and it worked like charm

Answer (score 0):

You have to set fancybox type option

```
$(".reasoning").fancybox({
'type': 'iframe'
});
```

Comment: dont need an iframe need ajax form so that my window object dom stays at the current window instead of iframe window as i need to perform some javascript operation after the form submit and doing from iframe i have to everytime use `window.parent` which dont want to use